# @font-face not working even after trying everything I could think of

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts

I really need help with `@font-face` code.
IT doesn't seem to see my font file.

I tried changing the path to anything I could think of, made new folders, renamed existing ones, put the font file in my root etc.

I'm testing in Firefox and Chrome.

Here are the codes that I tried in my CSS:

```
src: url(http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(http://www.thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(www.thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(../wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(../thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(/images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(../images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(images/Univers.ttf);
src: url(www.thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/Univers.ttf);
src: url(/Univers.ttf);
src: url(Univers.ttf);
src: url(../Univers.ttf);
```

Can you find out where I should put the font file or what to change in my CSS to get it to work?

(I also checked the similar questions here and elsewhere on the net and tried using [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) website to no avail.)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
bozdoz's suggestion doesn't work.
I used FontSquirrel to get the fonts.
This is the CSS:

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'lane';
    src: url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.eot');
    src: url('thttp://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.svg#LaneHumouresqueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}`

`h1{    font-size: 110px;
    font-family: 'lane', georgia, serif;
    color: #000000; 
    }`

I used the name 'lane' just because bozdoz had it.

All of the fonts are here:

`http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/`

and these are their names:

`univers-webfont.eot, univers-webfont.woof, univers-webfont.ttf, univers-webfont.svg`

Comment: Did you try with quotes around the url like `url("Univers.ttf");`?

Comment: Also have you specified `font-family: "MyFontName";` for your custom font?

Comment: Also could you post the whole font-face style and the html/css code where you use it to see if the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: Looking at your site, I believe you need to wrap the name in quotes: 'univers'.  Then you need to use 'univers' in one of your styles, such as my answer below: .font {font-family: 'univers'}.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with quotes as well. It doesn't matter whether I use single or double quotes, right?

Comment: No it doesn't matter.  Use my example code and change the urls to the absolute path: h t t p://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/Univers.ttf.  It should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@font-face behavior inconsistencies inside of @media query rules (IE9)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922339/font-face-behavior-inconsistencies-inside-of-media-query-rules-ie9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for your great, great help!
There was no problem with the `@font-face` code.
The problem was with my overall CSS.
You see, my CSS was written like this:

```
/*   
Info
*/

@media screen {
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html { background: black url(images/bg.jpg); }
body { font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, serif; }
article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section { display: block; }

@font-face {
font-family: 'lane';
src: url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.eot');
src: url('thttp://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://thefalljourneyindia.iblogger.org/wp-content/themes/thefalltheme/images/univers-webfont.svg#LaneHumouresqueRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

etc.
```

The problem was that `@font-face` wasn't seen because it was after `@media screen`!
After I put it in front of `@media screen` and after `/* Info */` it worked flawlessly.

Also, seems like I can use absolute and relative paths when using Wordpress...

Once again, thank you all for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using it correctly?  Here is the format for @font-face.  Notice the number of files.  You can use [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create all of the necessary fonts for cross-browser compatibility.  Also, it looks like you're using WordPress.  I believe you have to use absolute paths (i.e. the first one in your list) in CSS on WordPress.  Hope this helps.

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lane';
    src: url('type/lanehum-webfont.eot');
    src: url('type/lanehum-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('type/lanehum-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/lanehum-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/lanehum-webfont.svg#LaneHumouresqueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
.font { font-family:"lane", arial, serif; }
</style>
```

Comment: Also, note that @font-face only works on current browsers.  It's important to put alternative fonts after your custom font: e.g. arial, serif... etc.

Comment: Check the update in the original question. Unfortunately it doesn't work...
BTW, when I used my original code, it worked with simple HTML+CSS but when I used it as a Wordpress theme, it stopped working.

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem with WordPress somewhere.  It works here too: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/4frqN/ 
I'm interested to find out why this happens.

Comment: Got it!
It was just my stupidity...
I'd answer the question but don't have 100 rep yet and I can't write it all as a comment.
Perhaps you can write the answer if I send it to you... :D

Comment: Put it in your question, and mark someone here as the correct answer. You get better reputation for marking correct answers (I guess even if they weren't specifically correct in your case). :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf'); }
```

The font definition file must be relative to your css file.  So if your css is at:

```
/Content/css/main.css
```

Then your font must be located in the same folder.  If you specify

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('fonts/Delicious-Roman.otf'); }
```

Then your font definition would be at

```
/Content/css/fonts/Delicious-Roman.otf
```

You might want to verify that your server is not blocking your fonts from being downloaded.  Try the URL and see if you get a 404 or 403 at the given url.

Comment: I don't think he can use relative paths in WordPress css, which I believe he is using.

Comment: That would be this one:`src: url(images/Univers.ttf);`
And I don't know if I can use relative paths in Wordpress. :/

Comment: Seems like you can use both absolute and relative paths in Wordpress CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [fontSuirrel's](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) generator, their scripts have been vastly tested and compliant with many browsers. Choose advanced settings when generating your fonts. Certain browsers may not have the ability to use `ttf` as a font so they provide you with `eot` `woff` and `ttf`

Comment: well, the @font-face code block and the style code block that is calling `universe` in your font family.

Comment: It's `univers`, without the "e"...
Here: `@font-facce{font-family: univers; src: url(/images/Univers.ttf)}`

Comment: ok... you should come up with something really similar to what @bozdoz has answered with.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions from the comments as an answer:

Try with quotes:

```html
url("Univers.ttf");
```

Check you have font-family or otherwise you cannot use your font in your code:

```html
font-family: "MyFontName";
```

Your custom font family you would use in css like:

```css
p { font-family: "MyFontName", Arial, sans-serif; }
```